# How important is it to have multiple action per one page load?

Tags: php, mysql, html

In conventional web application there is single action per one button click from user. So clicking on **submit form**, **send email** or **change status**, **delete user** etc all this does **single action** per page load then shows status message.

I am creating new application and trying to decide the likelihood of ever needing **multiple actions that would run at one button click**.

What would be some the case scenario where want I could use this functionality?

E.g. currently I have one action supported

```
index.php?action=login&username=admin&password=123
```

I could have possibly two actions at once, this might not be great example of need for two actions at one page refresh but this is my question when do I need this functionality?

```
index.php?action=login&username=admin&password=123&action2=download_news&url=whatever.com
```

P.S. perhaps this could be useful if my application receives input from remote server rather than user?

To be more clear I am asking not how to do multiple things without reloading page.

Is there use case for one button  in app interface to run multiple system actions versus one action per button?

Comment: Off topic but just to mention; you shouldn't really have the password in the URL as that's typically saved in logs all over the place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course multiple actions can and sometimes should be taken with one button click. You might have a list of actions with check boxes. Or you might have a list of items on which you may act, with checkboxes indicating which ones should receive the action. A submit or "go" button could then launch the action.

If the actions taken are easily reversible, then you might not have a "go" button, instead having checking or unchecking the box immediately result in the action being done and undone via Ajax.

But if the actions are irreversible then the extra step of pressing "go" makes sense because you want the importance of the process to be clear.

Edit: I'll add a little more detail about how I implemented this.
The checkboxes, when checked, obviously would change the submitted form variables. I structure the checkbox variables depending on what should take place on the backend. As you may know, in HTML you can use brackets in the `name` attribute to create an array of values in your backend code. I would then have a method that takes that array and acts on all the items. That method could apply the same kind of process to the array of items. Or the method could call other methods specified in the array, an array of actions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can get more than one action out of a web page:

1. Implement an API that talks to a JSON Web Service,
2. Use AJAX, or
3. Add a "method" parameter to your POST.  In most MVC architectures, you get this capability for free.

In short, you need to learn a bit more about how all this works, and then the picture will become clearer to you.

Comment: I know about AJAX, question is not how to implement more than one action per page load. Do i need more than one action to runs at when user clicking only one button/link on page. and why

Comment: But i'd like to know about option 3 can you give me a link to tutorial or description of what you mean

Comment: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m2-controllers&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple actions?"  Naturally, you can do more than one thing after the button is pushed; all that takes is two method calls.

Comment: Two method calls would need some code or third method just to call each of them. I want to be able to call two totally unrelated methods simultaneously now or if i decide later in project life without need to write/edit any code for that. For example one method `loginUser($login, $password)` second `curlDownload($url)`. can be called from url arguments by me with **one request** to the site. or i can have button that will do this by just editing HTML no php editing involved. i know how to implement this. How likely that i will need to run two, three or more methods at once. is there use case?

Answer (score 0):

A pretty common pattern in web applications is to *redirect* the user after a login rather than trying to complicate the logic by performing multiple actions in the same request.  By default you redirect them to whatever your default landing page is but you have the option to set a target & send the user there instead.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how big the scope of an 'action' is.

For example, consider a button used to register. And consider registering involves creating a user in DB, sending an email to the user, and add a cookie for later connections.

Would that be 3 actions, or one ? For most people, this is only one action since you're doing only one thing, registering as a user.

Now checkboxes. Consider a button to launch different algorithms on a bunch of stats. You can tick multiple checkboxes and thus, apply different algorithms to these stats.

Would that be X actions, or one ? Again, this only looks like you're doing one thing only, which is applying algorithms.

I don't think the HTML should be responsible for such low level thinking as to using different 'actions' (I'd call these 'methods' instead) even though it may feel more flexible.